# How do I set the dns search domain in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, ubuntu-12.04

`/etc/resolv.conf` is dynamically generated from the contents of `/etc/network/interfaces`, which on my system contains a line like this:

```
dns-servers 8.8.8.8
```

How do I include the default search domain with this configuration?  If it matters, I'm running a pure Ubuntu Server configuration, with no X server installed.

Comment: @womble the edit changed the meaning of the question.

Comment: You really don't need all the mentions of 12.04.  Resolvconf has worked the same way for more then 5 years.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since you seem to be using resolvconf, you will want to use the `dns-search` option within your network interfaces file

```
#/etc/network/interfaces 
# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 10.2.37.4
    netmask 255.255.254.0
    gateway 10.2.37.1
    dns-nameservers 10.2.51.4 10.2.52.4
    dns-search example.org
```